# Is "rejected" correct here?

Tags: meaning, questions

> he company _____ the contract because of unfair terms.
>
> 1. liked
> 2. accepted
> 3. rejected
> 4. signed

I think "fair" means "not enough" so they *rejected* and *not accepted*, right?

Comment: You have already found the answer.

Comment: It should be ***his*** *company*. The sentence is grammatical (that change aside) with any of those words. Somebody who is unprincipled—say, the Devil—easily could accept (and like and sign) the contract *because* it was unfair. (The Devil would reject any contracts that *weren't* unfair.) The right context can support the use of any of the words.

Comment: Oh, no I am really sorry for this... I mispelled it should be "The company" Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> right?

Yes and no.

---

You got an incorrect meaning for "fair".

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair) (valid in the context of your sentence):

> fair = Just, equitable.
>
> *He must be given a fair trial.*

---

But the correct answer is indeed "3. rejected", meaning "not accepted".

Comment: Yes, I then thought of the meaning of "fairly" that means quite and so "unfair" I thought would mean not quite or not enough.. yes, I got it now Thanks so much for your answer it  really helped me :)